# collapsing successor of singular

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\lambda$ be a singular cardinal.  Is it consistent that there is a forcing of size $\lambda^+$ that collapses $\lambda^+$ while preserving all cardinals below $\lambda$?

(Note that even without the size requirement this implies a failure of the Jensen covering property, so such a forcing does not necessarily exist.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no and it follows easily from the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular uncountable cardinal and $|P|\leq \kappa.$ Then $\Vdash_P cf(\kappa)=|\kappa|.$

For a proof of the theorem see
[Singularizing forcing of "small" cardinality?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142086/singularizing-forcing-of-small-cardinality)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a consequence of stationary forcing. See P. Larson: The Stationary Tower, p. 60.

Comment: Isn't the stationary tower forcing much larger than $\lambda^+$?