# stationary tower forcing

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

It is known that if $\delta$ is a Woodin cardinal and $\kappa < \delta$, then the stationary tower forcing $\mathbb Q^\kappa_{<\delta}$ preserves cardinals up to $\kappa$ and forces $\delta = \kappa^+$.  Thus if there is a Woodin cardinal $\delta$ then there is a forcing preserving cardinals up to $\aleph_\omega$ and making $\delta = \aleph_{\omega+1}$.  But it is also known that $\mathbb Q^\kappa_{<\delta}$ is not $\delta$-c.c.

**Question:** Is there some large cardinal assumption that implies the existence of a cardinal $\kappa > \aleph_{\omega+1}$ and a $\kappa$-c.c. forcing $\mathbb P$ which preserves $\aleph_n$ for finite $n$ and makes $\kappa = \aleph_{\omega+1}$?

I'm no expert on these things, but naively I would suggest two possible approaches: (a) Find a large cardinal $\delta$ that implies the existence of a $\delta$-saturated tower of ideals with similar effects as the stationary tower.  (b) Find an inaccessible cardinal $\delta$ with a precipitous tower of ideals of height $\delta$ that preserves the $\aleph_n$'s but actually collapses $\delta$, so that $\delta^+$ is the witness.  **Update:** (b) is ruled out by [Mohammad's result here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142086/singularizing-forcing-of-small-cardinality)

**Note:**  It is consistent relative to large cardinals that there is some $\kappa$-c.c. forcing collapsing a regular $\kappa$ to be $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ while preserving cardinals below $\aleph_\omega$.  Namely an $\aleph_{\omega+2}$-saturated ideal on $\aleph_{\omega+1}$, which can be forced from a huge cardinal.  But I want to see if it is outright implied by large cardinals, because then it is much easier to combine with other things.

---

**New Idea:** Foreman-Magidor-Shelah show in "Martin's Maximum Part I" that if $\mu$ is regular and $\kappa > \mu$ is supercompact, then $\mathrm{Col}(\mu,<\kappa)$ forces that $NS_\mu$ is precipitous.  I believe this was improved by Goldring to a Woodin cardinal.  So perhaps for large $\kappa$, $\mathrm{Col}(\aleph_{\omega+1},<\kappa) * \dot{\mathcal{P}(\aleph_{\omega+1}) / NS}$ does the trick.  If we force below $cof(\omega_n)$ for $n > 0$, then we are sure to collapse $\kappa = \aleph_{\omega+2}$ (by a theorem of Shelah), and the whole forcing is $\kappa$-dense, so $\kappa^+$ should be the witness.  But the problem is, what happens below $\aleph_\omega$?  Despite being precipitous, could forcing with $NS_{\aleph_{\omega+1}}$ actually make $\kappa$ countable?  The proof of precipitousness given in the paper is a bit abstract so I have no idea how the generic ultrapower compares to the generic extension.

Comment: Mmmm... chain conditions. We [Yair and I] could have totally tried to tackle that in our work. Why didn't you ask that two months ago? :-)

Comment: Sorry, just thought of it. :-)

Comment: Although maybe it's possible to squeeze out of what we did something related to chain conditions. Let me think about it until Yair gets here. :-P

Comment: By the way, what happens if you take a Woodin which is a limit of Woodin cardinals, and iterate stationary towers up to that limit, with bounded support or something like that.

Comment: Good question, I don't know. Does the preservation of $\aleph_n$'s go through limit stages?

Comment: I don't see a reason that this will not go through limit stages (which are supposedly full support below $\delta$ itself, "The Last Woodin" (which as a side note should be a totally awesome sci-fi movie about the last set theorists in a generic, collapsing universe (I'll stop now))).

Comment: Btw we'd want Easton support to get the chain condition. But there is an easy example of a full support $\omega$-length iteration of forcings adding no reals, while at the limit $\omega_1$ is collapsed. (Keep shooting clubs...)

Comment: Sure, Easton support it is, then. I still don't know what to quite tell you about the $\aleph_n$'s. Suffices to say, I hope they don't get collapsed. :-)

Comment: Perhaps a simpler question, is it even consistent?

Comment: Good question, I will address that in an edit.

Answer (score 3):

**This may not be an answer but it is longer than be a comment:**

Starting from a supercompact cardinal $\kappa$ an inaccessible $\lambda$ above it, we can construct a model $M$ of ZFC in which $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$ and $\lambda=\aleph_{\omega+1}.$ The model in an intermediate submodel of a supercompact Prikry forcing with suitable collapses.

I think using an analysis similar to Foreman-Woodin's paper "GCH can fail everywhere", we can show that this intermdiate submodel $M$ is a $\lambda-c.c.$ extension of the ground model.

Now find another intermediate submodel $N \subset M$ of the ground model which is essentially the Prikry extension of the ground which makes $\kappa$ into $\aleph_\omega,$ preserves cardinals above $\kappa$ and it makes the cardinal structure below $\aleph_\omega$ the same as in $M$.

Now consider $M$ as a generic extension of $N$, which makes $\lambda$ into $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ and is $\lambda-c.c.$ extension of $N$.

Comment: When I asked if it's even consistent, this was the sort of idea that I had in mind. Thanks for reinforcing my intuition!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your welcome, in fact I learnt such an idea from Prof. Magidor; your supervisor!.

Comment: How do you show the model $N$ exists?

Comment: By defining over the ground model a Prirky forcing with suitable collapses, and then defining a weak projection from supercompact prikry forcing into it (to guarantee that the $\omega-$sequence added by them and the collapses are the same, so that the cardinal structure below $\aleph_\omega$ is the same in both $M$ and $N$).

Comment: @MohammadGolshani: You results is stronger: Let $N = V[G]$, where $G$ is a generic for the standard Prikry forcing on $\kappa$ with collapses (the normal measure on $\kappa$ projected from the measure on $P_\kappa \lambda$). In this model, for every $\mu$, let $\mathbb{R}$ be the quotient between the supercompact Prikry forcing with collapses using the measure on $P_\kappa \mu^+$ (from the ground model), and $G$. This forcing is $\mu$-centered if $\mu > \kappa$.

Comment: cont: In particular - in $N$, the fact that for  unboundedly many cardinals $\mu$ it is possible collapse cardinals below them and force $\mu$ to be $\aleph_{\omega + 1}$ in a $\mu$.c.c. forcing is indestructible by any forcing of size $<\lambda$ that doesn't change the $\aleph_n$-s.

Comment: @YairHayut Thanks for extra information. What is the most interesting thing for me is that $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ of $M$ is inaccessible in $HOD^M$, because $HOD^M \subseteq N.$ I have not written all the details of this fact, but this is the main motivation of my work on this project. Do you know if it is known it is consistent that $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ is inaccessible in $HOD$?

Comment: My next project is to extend the above construction to build a model in which all uncountable cardinals are inaccessible in $HOD$, but it seems much more complicated.

Comment: @YairHayut: This looks very useful.  Can you sketch the indestructibility you claim?

Comment: @MonroeEskew: I spoke too soon. The indestructibility argument that I had only works for $\kappa$-distributive forcing from the ground model. Maybe one can extend it to a large class of forcings. The idea is that for a forcing $\mathbb{P}$ of cardinality $\mu < \lambda$ as above, the supercompact Prikry forcing for $P_\kappa\mu$ will add a $V$-generic for $\mathbb{P}$. The quotient forcing $\mathbb{R}_{\mu^\prime}/\mathbb{P}$, for $\mu^\prime > \mu$ is still $\mu^\prime^+$.c.c. We need to deal we the mutual generity of the Prikry sequences and this can be done by adding a Cohen real.